# placeholder transparent after uptade to angular material 6.4.7

Tags: angular, angular-material, placeholder

After updating Angular Material from `v6.0.1` to `v6.4.7` all the `mat-form-field`s of the application has the class `.mat-form-field-hide-placeholder` that basically add the  following code: `-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;`

And now all the placeholders are transparent.

[image: Screenshot of Chrome DevTools]

this is an example of how we use placeholder with mat-form-field

```html
<mat-form-field *ngIf="option">
    <mat-select class="irregularselector"
                [(ngModel)]="selectedOption"
                placeholder="Choose one..."
                (selectionChange)="onSelectedOption()">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let opt of irregularOpts;" value={{opt.uuid}}> 
            {{opt.name}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
 </mat-form-field>
```

Where we want to display the placeholder describe above.

Do you know why this is happening, or on how to avoid this class?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I have discovered that this behaviour is related with the new apearance of the mat-form-field that by default is legacy. If I choose standard the class mat-form-field-hide-placeholder disapear.

Comment: Can you elaborate ? I have the same issue but I'm not sure what you mean about "If I choose standard" where ? how ?